# do we have to design config.php, database.php and general php files or we can use it from php library

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in php and my questin is that while backend administration of a site do we have to design config.php, database.php and **general php files** or we can use it from php library???

Comment: I don't think library is needed for setting a simple environment

Answer (score 1):

you just need to configure the `config.php` where you have to chage the following things according to your website.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database_name'); //Your database name here

define('DB_USER', 'root'); //Your name of user

define('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin');//password of your phpmyadmin
```

**Note:**
  The  above changes are for dummy you have to change it as per your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better and faster to use already tested libraries

and the best this is to probably use a framework like CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Zend FW

I particularly recommend [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) it seems to be the most popular one around atm, and it is very simple to use for anyone